# Translations not working with Symfony 3.3, KNP Doctrine Behaviors & Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, translation, symfony-3.3

Could someone explain me what i am doing wrong. I have an entity with classes Actualite and ActualiteTranslation.

I created ActualiteAdmin class with sonanta:admin:generate.

Everything is working as expected. I debug fields with dump($actualite) in the controller and i see that each fields are well displayed :

```html
array:1 [▼
  0 => Actualite {#742 ▼
    -id: 8
    -date: DateTime {#806 ▶}
    -image: null
    #translations: PersistentCollection {#709 ▼
      -snapshot: array:1 [ …1]
      -owner: Actualite {#742}
      -association: array:16 [ …16]
      -em: EntityManager {#789 …11}
      -backRefFieldName: "translatable"
      -typeClass: ClassMetadata {#738 …}
      -isDirty: false
      #collection: ArrayCollection {#662 ▼
        -elements: array:1 [▼
          "fr" => ActualiteTranslation {#705 ▼
            #actucategorie: "categorie"
            #alt: "image"
            #titre: "Page Facebook"
            #article: "mon article"
            #id: 4
            #locale: "fr"
            #translatable: Actualite {#742}
            #slug: "page-facebook"
          }
        ]
      }
      #initialized: true
    }
    #newTranslations: null
    #currentLocale: "fr"
    #defaultLocale: "fr"
  }
]
```

I have thir error in Twig Template when using {{actualite.translations.titre}}:

Key "translations" for array with keys "0" does not exist.

This is the code I use :

```html
namespace BDN\ActualitesBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;

/**
 * Actualite
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="bdn_actualite")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BDN\ActualitesBundle\Repository\ActualiteRepository")
 * 
 */
class Actualite
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;
    
    /**
     * @param $method
     * @param $args
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        if (!method_exists(self::getTranslationEntityClass(), $method)) {
            $method = 'get' . ucfirst($method);
        }

        return $this->proxyCurrentLocaleTranslation($method, $args);
    }
    
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $image;
        
    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return null
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param string $image
     *
     * @return null
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }
}
```

```html
namespace BDN\ActualitesBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;

/**
 * ActualiteTranslation
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="bdn_actualite_translation")
 * 
 */
class ActualiteTranslation
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation;
    use ORMBehaviors\Sluggable\Sluggable;
    
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="actucategorie", type="string", length=50)
     */
    protected $actucategorie;
    
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="alt", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $alt;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="titre", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    protected $titre;
    
    public function getSluggableFields()
    {
        return ['titre'];
    }

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="article", type="text")
     */
    protected $article;

    /**
     * Set actucategorie
     *
     * @param string $actucategorie
     *
     * @return ActualiteTranslation
     */
    public function setActucategorie($actucategorie)
    {
        $this->actucategorie = $actucategorie;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get actucategorie
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getActucategorie()
    {
        return $this->actucategorie;
    }

    /**
     * Set alt
     *
     * @param string $alt
     *
     * @return ActualiteTranslation
     */
    public function setAlt($alt)
    {
        $this->alt = $alt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get alt
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAlt()
    {
        return $this->alt;
    }

    /**
     * Set titre
     *
     * @param string $titre
     *
     * @return ActualiteTranslation
     */
    public function setTitre($titre)
    {
        $this->titre = $titre;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get titre
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitre()
    {
        return $this->titre;
    }

    /**
     * Set article
     *
     * @param string $article
     *
     * @return ActualiteTranslation
     */
    public function setArticle($article)
    {
        $this->article = $article;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get article
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getArticle()
    {
        return $this->article;
    }
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<?php

namespace BDN\ActualitesBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use A2lix\TranslationFormBundle\Form\Type\TranslationsType;

class ActualiteAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    /**
     * @param DatagridMapper $datagridMapper
     */
    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add('id')
            ->add('date')
            ->add('image')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param ListMapper $listMapper
     */
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->add('id')
            ->add('date')
            ->add('image')
            ->add('_action', null, array(
                'actions' => array(
                    'show' => array(),
                    'edit' => array(),
                    'delete' => array(),
                ),
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormMapper $formMapper
     */
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('date')
            ->add('image')
            ->add("translations", TranslationsType::class, array(
                "fields" => array(
                    "actucategorie" => [],
                    "alt" => [],
                    "titre" => [],
                    "slug" => ["display" => false,],
                    "article" => [ "field_type" => "text"],
                ),
            ))
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param ShowMapper $showMapper
     */
    protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {
        $showMapper
            ->add('id')
            ->add('date')
            ->add('image')
            ->add("translations", TranslationsType::class, array(
                "required_locales" => ['fr'],
                    "fields" => array(
                        "actucategorie" => [],
                        "alt" => [],
                        "titre" => [],
                        "article" => [ "field_type" => "text"],
                ),
            ))
        ;
    }
}
```

```html
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block page %}

    <section class="row jumbotron">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <h3>{{ actualite.getTitre() }}</h3>
                    <p class="categorie">Le {{ actualite.date | date('d/m/Y') }} | Catégorie : {{ actualite.translate.actucategorie }}</p>
                </div>
                {% if actualite.image is not null %}
                    <div class="col-xs-3  hidden-xs">
                        <img src="{{ asset('actualite.image') }}" class="img-thumbnail img-shop"  alt="{{ actualite.alt }}">
                    </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="row content-actualite">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    {{ actualite.translate.article }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
{% endblock %}
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Denis